# return login success from a web api to an mvc 4 application

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, authentication, asp.net-web-api

my colleague and myself are working on an application form with login functionality the user logs in from the mvc 4 app and there details are submitted to the web api to be checked against the values held in the database once verified the web api returns a loginResult class that contains the error message (if any) and a bool for stating whether it has been successful or not.

at the mvc 4 application level the code below is used to submit the login details to the web api:

**Login Action**

```
[HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public async Task<ActionResult> Login(AccountViewModel model)
    {
        if (!ModelState.IsValid) return View("Login", model);

        await _client.PostAsJsonAsync("api/Applicant/CheckApplicant", model)
           .ContinueWith((postTask) => postTask.Result.EnsureSuccessStatusCode());

        var service = DependencyResolver.Current.GetService<IApplyService>();

        var loginResult = service.GetLoginResult();

        var loginSuccess = loginResult.LoginSuccess;

        if (loginSuccess != null && (bool) loginSuccess)
        {
            FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie(model.Email, model.RememberMe);

            return RedirectToRoute("Terms And Conditions");
        }

        return View("Login");
    }
```

the login details are then received at the web api in this method:

**Check Applicant Method**

```
public String CheckApplicant(Applicant applicant)
    {
        Int32 passwordFailureTimeoutMins = Convert.ToInt32(System.Configuration.ConfigurationSettings.AppSettings["PasswordFailureTimeoutMins"]);
        Int32 passwordFailureAttempts = Convert.ToInt32(System.Configuration.ConfigurationSettings.AppSettings["PasswordFailureAttempts"]);

        ApplicantRepository applicantRepository = new ApplicantRepository();
        Applicant applicantDB = applicantRepository.GetById(applicant.Email);
        LoginResult loginResult = new LoginResult();
        PasswordHelper passwordHelper = new PasswordHelper();

        if (applicantDB == null)
        {
            loginResult.LoginSuccess = false;
            loginResult.LoginError = "Your password or login may not be correct.";
        }
        else
        {                 
            bool loginFailureCheck;              
            if (applicantDB.LoginFailureCount > passwordFailureAttempts)
            {
                System.TimeSpan diffResult = DateTime.Now.Subtract(Convert.ToDateTime(applicantDB.LastLoginFailure));
                if (diffResult.Minutes < passwordFailureTimeoutMins)
                {
                    loginFailureCheck = false;
                }
                else
                {
                    loginFailureCheck = true;
                }
            }
            else
            {
                loginFailureCheck = true;
            }

            if (passwordHelper.CheckPassword(applicant.Password, applicantDB.Password))
            {
                if(loginFailureCheck)
                {
                    if(applicantDB.AccountActive)
                    {                        
                        loginResult.LoginSuccess = true;
                        loginResult.LoginError = "Login Successful.";
                        applicantDB.LastLoginFailure = null;
                        applicantDB.LastLoginSuccess = DateTime.Now;
                        applicantDB.LoginFailureCount = 0;
                        applicantRepository.Update(applicantDB);                    
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        loginResult.LoginSuccess = false;
                        loginResult.LoginError = "This account has been permanently banned.";
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    loginResult.LoginSuccess = false;
                    loginResult.LoginError = "This account is now temporarily disabled please wait " + passwordFailureTimeoutMins + " minutes before trying again";
                    applicantDB.LastLoginFailure = DateTime.Now;
                    applicantDB.LoginFailureCount = applicantDB.LoginFailureCount + 1;
                    applicantRepository.Update(applicantDB);
                }
            }
            else
            {
                loginResult.LoginSuccess = false;
                loginResult.LoginError = "Your password or login may not be correct.";
                applicantDB.LastLoginFailure = DateTime.Now;
                applicantDB.LoginFailureCount = applicantDB.LoginFailureCount + 1;
                applicantRepository.Update(applicantDB);
            }
        }
        return JsonConvert.SerializeObject(loginResult);
    }
```

as you can see it returns a JsonConvert.SerializeObject(loginResult).

when this is done the process returns to the Login ActionResult as above it then moves to the GetLoginResult() method as shown below:

**GetLoginResult**

```
public LoginResult GetLoginResult()
    {
        const string uri = "http://localhost:55830/api/Applicant/CheckApplicant";

        using (var httpClient = new HttpClient())
        {
            var response = httpClient.GetStringAsync(uri);
            return JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<LoginResult>(response.Result);
        }
    }
```

when it get to this point it returns an error 405 method not allowed.

How  do I consume the loginResult at the mvc 4 app level and what is the best way of sending the loginResult from the web api?

Any advice would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure what exactly you are trying to do but are you making a GET to read the result of the previous POST? You can read the response message of POST to get the result, like this.

```
public async Task<ActionResult> Login(AccountViewModel model)
{
    if (!ModelState.IsValid) return View("Login", model);

    var message = await _client.PostAsJsonAsync
                       ("api/Applicant/CheckApplicant", model);

    message.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();

    LoginResult result = await message.Content.ReadAsAsync<LoginResult>();

    // do other stuff here
}
```

Change the web API action method to return `LoginResult` directly. The framework will serialize it for you.

```
public LoginResult CheckApplicant(Applicant applicant)
{

}
```